# Data augmentation after image segmentation

Tags: python, keras, image-segmentation, data-augmentation

Lets assume i have a little dataset. I want to implement data augmentation. First i implement image segmentation (after this, image will be binary image) and then implement data augmentation. Is this a good way?

Answer (score 1):

For image augmentation in segmentation and instance segmentation, you have to either no change the positions of the objects contained in the image by manipulating colors for example, or modify these positions by applying translations and rotation.

So, yes this way works, but you have to take into consideration the type of data you have and what you are looking to achieve. Data augmentation isn't a ready to-go process with good results everywhere.

In case you have a:

- **Semantic segmentation** :  Each pixel of your image has a row `i` and a column `j` which are labeled as its enclosing object. This means having your main image `I` and a label image `L` with its same size linking every pixel to its object label. In this case, your data augmentation is applied to both `I` and `L`, giving a combination of the two transformed images.
- **Instance segmentation** : Here we generate a mask for every instance of the original image and the augmentation is applied to all of them including the original, then from these transformed masks we get our new instances.

**EDIT**:
Take a look at [CLoDSA](https://github.com/joheras/CLoDSA) (Classification, Localization, Detection and Segmentation Augmentor) it may help you implement your idea.

Comment: I have a biomedical images dataset. I implement U-Net architecture for image segmentation. After this segmentation, i have binary images. (Tumor pixels are white(1) non-tumor pixels black(0) ). And then i implement translations for data augmentation on this segmented binary images. For classification, i used vgg-16. Model accuracy in validation dataset is good for me. I was be sure that this is a good idea or not.

Comment: Yes it works fine with your case i suppose, knowing your images samples you might even think about zooming in case the images aren't standarized(issued from the same source too) or horizontally flipping if the human organs on the radio-images allow you to do so. Maybe confront your model to some test-time augmentation too to see how it performs.

Comment: In my problem, tumor area can be anywhere in the image. So translation is fit for this problem. First i split randomly as train and validation. After this, i implement same data augmentation to train and validation. Can we call this operation test-time data augmentation?

Comment: No, it's quiet different since we are referring to the test dataset and not the validation one(which means the model remains unchanged). The idea is simple, to test a given model , we augment the test dataset and a prediction is made for each image, and each prediction contains a probability of the image belonging to each class and we apply an average weighted ensemble approach to get the prediction. It is easily implemented in Keras, hope this helps you: [TTA Guide](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-test-time-augmentation-to-improve-model-performance-for-image-classification/)

Comment: I understand. Thank you for feedback. May i ask last thing? Is it okay implement the same data augmentation in train and validation after splitting? Because all of the metrics validation score is so close to train score. Can we call good model?

Comment: You're welcome. In general when it comes to a "good model", it is always recomended that you apply the augmentation only to the train and not the validation, but again it all depends on the model and the data itself. In your case, i guess the translations are likely to improve your validation.

Answer (score 0):

**In case your dataset is small, you should add data-augmentation during the training. It is important to change the original image & the targets (masks) in the same way !!**.

For example, If an image is rotated 90 degrees, then its mask should also be rotated 90 degrees. Since you are using **Keras** library, You should check if the `ImageDataGenerator` also changes the target images (masks), along with the inputs. If it doesn't, You can implement the augmentations by yourself. This repository shows how it is done in OpenCV here:
https://github.com/kochlisGit/random-data-augmentations